# disable some of the rows in a column

Tags: php

```
function arrayToTabledownload($arr) {
    if ($arr > 0) {
        foreach($arr[0] as $t=>$v)
            $colnams[] = $t;
    }
    $r = '<form action="upd.php" method="POST">';
    $r .=' <table   cellpadding="5" border="1" style="width:250px;"><tr>';

    for ($i=0; $i<count($colnams); $i++)  {
        $r .= "<td>$colnams[$i]</td>";
    }     
    $r .=   '<td>UPDATE</td>';
    $r .=   '</tr>';
    for ($i=0; $i<count($arr) ; $i++)  {
        $r .='<tr>';
        for ($ii=0; $ii < count($colnams); $ii++)  {
            $e= serialize($arr[$i][$colnams[$ii]]);
            $j=unserialize($e);
            $r .="<td><input type='text' name='id[]' value='$j'></td>";
        }
        $r .=   '<td><input type="submit" name="up" value="UPDATE" ></td>'; 
        $r .="</tr>";
    }     
    $r .=   '</table>';
    $r.='</form>';
    return $r;
}
```

This is my function , it is used to convert the array into the table now I was thinking to make some of the fields disable so that the user can update the other fields which are not disable . I have 8 columns .

Comment: add `disable` or `readonly` attribute in your html field.

Comment: I have no idea about the jquery , I am working on a php

Comment: can you give some idea

Comment: Well, first you should format your code so that it is readable. Second, you are using `$arr` both as a number and an array, which does not make much sense. Third, `$colnams` is defined inside one block and then used inside another block (that will not work). Fourth, well... I did not bother. Fix up your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable an input just say it:

```
<input type='text' name='id[]' value='$j' disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score 0):

if we want to disable it then try this:

```
 $r .="<input type='text' name='id[]' value='$j' disabled></td>";
```

if we want to disable and hide it from user then try this:

```
  $r .="<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='$j' disabled></td>";
```